# Django remove form error for unique field

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a Django model with a `customer_code` field that is set to unique but only some users will have an assigned value for this field. Other users simply use this code to find the user who provided their code as a reference number. When they submit the form however it raises an error as the field is set to unique.

I would like to remove this error upon validation. The user does not get saved with the value it is set to `None` before save. I have tried doing this so far with a custom `clean()` method on the form:

```
def clean(self):
    super(EmployeeForm, self).clean()
    if 'customer_code' in self.errors:
        del self._errors['customer_code']
    return self
```

But this has not been working. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the end of method you should return `cleaned_data`

```
 cleaned_data = super(EmployeeForm, self).clean()
 ...
 return cleaned_data
```